# Time for request route from Google API

Tags: c#, datetime, google-maps-api-2

I'm trying to make a request for public transport route to the Google maps API. I must specify a departure time(number of seconds from January 1, 1970). I thought that in C # it is enough to use `DateTime.Now.Thick` or `DateTime.UtcNow.Thick`, but ia always get response

> "status" : "INVALID_REQUEST"

In the working example from Google indicates the time "1343605500" - I can not understand how I get such a number.

Comment: Are you really using the [deprecated Google Maps API v2](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/reference)?  I didn't think that supported transit directions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where did you get `.Thick` from?  That's not a valid property on a `Datetime`.

You should do something like:

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.UtcNow;
DateTime epoch = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
int s = (int)(dt - epoch).TotalSeconds;
```